# Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I copy symfony2 app from backup. I remove cache and try composer install or composer update - get error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found in /home/div/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1033
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" ,  "mea":"vendor/Mea/CoreBundle/"}
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",

        "jbafford/password-strength-bundle": "dev-master",

        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",

        "weotch/phpthumb": "dev-master",
        "meenie/javascript-packer": "dev-master",
        "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master",
        "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",

        "zetacomponents/mail": "dev-master",

        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",

        "instaclick/translation-editor-bundle": "dev-master",

        "endroid/qrcode": "1.*@dev",

        "whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "dev-master",

        "ddeboer/data-import": "dev-master",

        "payum/payum-bundle": "*@stable",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "*@stable",

        "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "0.*@dev",

        "twilio/sdk": "dev-master",

        "vich/uploader-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",

        "astina/social-links-bundle":"dev-master",

        "Mea/CoreBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/InvoiceBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/PostBoxBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/Emailer": "dev-master",

        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meacorebundle.git"
        },{
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meainvoicebundle.git"
        },{
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/emailer.git"
        },{
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/postboxbundle.git"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

any idea how to fix this app ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had the same error while restoring one of our backup.

In our automated backup, there was a rule to not include the symfony `cache` directory. The rule was too permissive and the source folder `vendor/doctrine/cache` has been excluded too.

Check in your vendor dir if source files are here and restore them if not.

This has fixed our problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe manually try to delete the cache folder

or try

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Check vendor/doctrine/cache  directory.

It should not be empty